# User cannot book a room resource in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, calendar

Im having a problem with a specific user not being able to book a room resource.  No error message is generated at all.  The user attempts to add the room as a meeting resource and it simply doesnt register with the resources calendar.  I have tested the resource with other accounts and other rooms for this user but it is only this room that is having issues for this user.

This Exchange server was migrated from 2007 to 2010.  All rooms except for the problem room were created back on Exchange 2007.  This new room was created with Exchange 2010.  Maybe this clue has something to do with the problem?

This is a paste of the mailboxes folder permission:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-MailboxFolderPermission -identity room125:\calendar

RunspaceId   : 448ab44a-4c2a-4403-b46c-fce1106c0823
FolderName   : Calendar
User         : Default
AccessRights : {Author}
Identity     : Default
IsValid      : True

RunspaceId   : 448ab44a-4c2a-4403-b46c-fce1106c0823
FolderName   : Calendar
User         : Anonymous
AccessRights : {None}
Identity     : Anonymous
IsValid      : True
```

Comment: If the user tries to organize a meeting and add the room to the Scheduling Assistant in Outlook, does it say something like `"Cannot open the free/busy information"` ?

Comment: Yes this is what it says to the user in Outlook.

Comment: Does it work if done via OWA instead of Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running this.

```
Set-mailboxfolderpermission -identity room125:\calendar -user Default -AccessRights Reviewer
```